# how to use aggregate functions subquery in the main query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my database schema

```
Horse(horseId, horseName, age, gender, registration, stableId)
Owner(ownerId, lname, fname)
Owns(horseId, ownerId)
Stable(stableId, stableName, location, colors)
Trainer(trainerId, lname, fname, stableId)
Race(raceId, raceName, trackName, raceDate, raceTime)
RaceResults(raceId, horseId, results, prize)
Track(trackName, location, length)
```

I want to write this as a query:

For every horse that has run more than three races, list the horse name, total winnings and number of races run for each horse. The column names should be "Horse Name", "Winnings", and "Races". The result should be sorted by the winnings in descending order.

I've written this subquery as a beginning:

```
SELECT horseid, COUNT( horseid ) AS NumberOfRaces, SUM( prize ) winnings
FROM raceresults
GROUP BY horseid
HAVING COUNT( horseid ) >3
```

But how can I use the aggregate functions results {NumberOfRaces and winnings} in the main query?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: You are pretty close in your example SQL, you really should be able to do it with a single query, no sub-query needed.    Look up JOIN to get the horse's name and ORDER BY to get the proper sorting

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect to determine the aggregate values by the key you want and inner join it back to the main table.  I'm going to pseudo code this and let you put it together...does seem like a homework assignment.

```
Select id, sum(winnings) from table group by id
```

This results in a list of id's and their winning (same concept for any aggregate, not just this sum).  You can have several aggregates at this level... id, sum(winnings), count(winnings), avg(winnings) will work in one statement).  Put a set of brackets around it and call it a subquery.  join this back to your original statement...

```
...
from
(select id, sum(winnings) as winnings) a
inner join horse h on h.id = a.id
```

You can now refer to h.* or a.winnings as columns related to that ID.  Inner join will mean horses without winnings are dropped, a left join will show all regardless of winnings.